# How to view the value of non zero return type of C# program in linux terminal where mono is used to run C# code?

Tags: c#, linux, terminal, mono, return-value

I am using Ubuntu Linux OS and mono compiler to compile and run C# code in terminal.

I have a file named hello.cs having the following C# code:

```
using System;

namespace MyApp {
    class MyProg {
        static int Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            return 42;
        } 
    }
}
```

To create executable I use the following command in terminal:

```
mcs -out:hello.exe hello.cs
mono hello.exe
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```

Now in Windows command prompt command to view the return value is -

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Output:

```
42
```

Now what is the corresponding linux terminal command to view the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the exit status of the last cmd:

```
$ mono hello.exe
$ echo $?
```

If you want to save it for eval later, save to a env. var:

```
$ mono hello.exe
$ lastError=$?
$ echo $lastError
```